# When putting [Authorize] on the Home controller, return RedirectToAction("Index","Home") in Login method of Account controller can't work.why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
  var usr = db.Register.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && u.Password == user.Password);
                    if (usr != null)
                    {
                        Session["UserID"] = usr.UserID.ToString();
                        Session["UserName"] = usr.UserName.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


                    }
```

When I put breakpoint on [HttpPost]Login method and debug line by line I noticed that control can't go the Home controller and login page is displayed

Comment: You should take a look at Asp Identity which make ti easy to authenticate a user.

Comment: Ok I will try it, but why my current scenario is not working?

Comment: Your not doing any authorization (i.e. creating the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`). Adding something to `Session` has nothing to do with authorization

Comment: Please tell me how to create FormAuthenticationTicket in asp.net mvc 4